# Bootstrap menu hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found one problem with menu in Twitter Bootstrap 3 (3.1.1). Tab "kontakt" is a <"li" class="active">Kontakt<"/li">
and tab "Galeria zdjęć" is a <"li">Galeria zdjęć<"/li"> (without brackets before and after li). How can I avoid this situation? http://scr.hu/2p5g/u5m8e

As You can see shadow from "Galeria zdjęć" is behind tab "Kontakt". Is it possible to change this that shadow would be before next tab?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the shadow to abruptly quit on the right side?

Comment: http://scr.hu/2p5g/jzpmw I want excatly as on the picture. Shadow on "top".

Comment: OK, then add `z-index:2; position:relative;` when the element is on hover.

Comment: Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/fxe4A/

Comment: Great. It was so easy. I'm angry on myself. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to use `z-index` and `position:relative` to achieve this:

So what you need to do is add this to the elements that need this effect applied:

```
.button { position:relative; z-index:1; }

.button:hover { z-index:2; /* add your box-shadow code here */ }
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/fxe4A/)**